# For loop doesn't read all the value in the list - dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

My for loop does not read all the values in the range (2004,2012) which is super odd. When I try a simple function in my for loop such as return a, I do see that it read all the values in the range. However, when I use pd.read_json, it just does not work the same. I converted the data into dataframe but only one year is showing up in my dataframe. Am I missing something in my for loop?

```
test = range(2004, 2012)
testlist = list(test)

for i in testlist:
     a = f"https://api.census.gov/data/{i}/cps/basic/jun?get=GTCBSA,PEMNTVTY&for=state:*"
     b = pd.read_json(a) 
     c= pd.DataFrame(b.iloc[1:,]).set_axis(b.iloc[0,], axis="columns", inplace=False)
     c['year'] = i
```

[image]

Comment: `c= pd.DataFrame(...)` overwrites `c` on every pass through the loop

Comment: I'm assuming instead of ```yearslist```, you meant ```testlist```?

Comment: @Nick does that mean I will have to make a list for b before doing the `c= pd.DataFrame(...)` ?

Comment: You could do that, or just add the rows from `b` to `c` on each pass through the loop

Comment: @ewong That's correct. Sorry, just edited

Comment: @Nick I tried doing `c= pd.DataFrame(pd.read_json(a).iloc[1:,]).set_axis(pd.read_json(a).iloc[0,], axis="columns", inplace=False)` but it gave me the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently overwriting `c` in each pass of the loop. Instead, you need to [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat) the new data to the end of it:

```py
test = range(2004, 2012)
testlist = list(test)

c = pd.DataFrame()
for i in testlist:
     a = f"https://api.census.gov/data/{i}/cps/basic/jun?get=GTCBSA,PEMNTVTY&for=state:*"
     b = pd.read_json(a) 
     b = pd.DataFrame(b.iloc[1:,]).set_axis(b.iloc[0,], axis="columns", inplace=False)
     b['year'] = i
     c = pd.concat([c, b])
```

Output:

```
0      GTCBSA PEMNTVTY state  year
1           0      316     2  2004
2           0       57     2  2004
3           0       57     2  2004
4           0       57     2  2004
5       22900       57     5  2004
...       ...      ...   ...   ...
133679      0      120    56  2011
133680      0       57    56  2011
133681      0       57    56  2011
133682      0       57    56  2011
133683      0       57    56  2011

[1087063 rows x 4 columns]
```

Note you don't need to convert a `range` to a `list` to iterate it. You can simply do

```py
for i in range(2004, 2012):
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. Is there a way to make that '2004' in the header to become 'year' ?

Comment: @dspassion that was a typo, the column header will be `year`, not `2004`. I've updated the answer.